# How do I enable 5000 port on my server using security group?

Tags: security, firewall, iptables, amazon-web-services

I checked all question to enable port.

Tried with

- `sudo ufw allow 5000`
- `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT`

Also enabled port on my security group.

Outbound

[image: Outbounde security group]

inbound

[image: Inbound security group]

Still when I open my website it says:

```
This site can't be reached
```

Am I missing anything? Are above rules are correct and secure?

Answer (score 0):

You have no inbound rule for port 5000 listed.  Only 80, 22, and 443.

Add an inbound rule.

Outbound rules are from the webserver, Inbound rules are to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. allow port 5000 (v6) at Security group Inbound rules
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDITC.png)
2. setup listen port: 0.0.0.0:5000
3. `sudo ufw allow 5000`
4. `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: you have to setup 0.0.0.0:5000 in your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).